# Difference between "undefined" and "does not exist"

Tags: calculus, terminology

What is the difference between the terms "undefined" and "does not exist", especially in the context of differential calculus?

Most calculus materials state, for example, that $\frac{d}{dx}{|x|}$ **does not exist** at $x = 0$.  Why don't we say that the derivative is **undefined** at $x = 0$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the particular example you gave: The derivative is defined as $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ and, as it is with limits, this limit may or may not exist. In the case $f(x) = |x|$ and $x=0$ the limit just **does not exist** and hence, this is the right wording. On the other hand there *are* possible definitions of a derivative of $f(x) = |x|$ at zero (e.g. using convex analysis one may define it to be the whole interval $[-1,1]$) and hence, it seems appropriate to say that the derivative **is undefined**.

In general "does not exists" and "is undefined" are very different things at a practical level. The former says that there is a definition for something which does not lead to a mathematical object in a specific case. The latter says that there is just no definition for a specific case. Of course, one can interchange both formulation some times (as in you example, at least in my opinion).

Comment: I've changed the example to $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: Why?$\mbox{}\mbox{}$

Comment: Alright, I've rolled it back.

Comment: Indeed, editing the question such that right answers get wrong is not always a good idea. If you ask for the function $f(x) = 1/x$ and whether the derivative exists or is undefined at $x=0$, then the answer would be (in my understanding) that the derivative is undefined (because its definition involves the term $f(0)$ which is undefined).

Comment: By your saying that "there is a definition for something which does not lead to a mathematical object in a specific case", do you mean that the result is defined, but is something like $\infty$?

Comment: Not exactly. It is the same with limits of sequences of real numbers: You may have a limit or not. In the latter case you not necessarily have "a limit $\infty$, e.h. there could be "oscillation" between $+1$ and $-1$...

Comment: So if we take the limit of log(x) at x tending to -3 , the limit will be undefined. But saying "limit doesn't exist" is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

There is a little subtlety not addressed so far:

Given a function $f:\ A\to\Bbb R$ on an open set $A\subset\Bbb R$ and a point $x\in A$, you can ask whether $f$ is differentiable at $x$. The function $f$ is *differentiable at $x$* (or: *has a derivative at $x$*) if the limit
$$\lim_{h\to0}{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}\tag{1}$$
**exists** and is finite. This limit is  called the *derivative of $f$ at $x$* and is denoted by $f'(x)$.

The set $A'$ of all $x\in A$ where the limit $(1)$ exists, is the domain of a *new function* $f'$ associated to $f$. This  new function is called the *derivative* of $f$.

When $x\in A'$ then we say that $f'$ is **defined** at $x$.

Comment: Continuing with your example, say $x\notin A'$. Then would we say that $f'(x)$ **does not exist** or **is undefined** or both?

Comment: (bump) I would also appreciate an answer to the above comment!